# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\messages.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main}

Tags: php, .htaccess

after the registration process, the data is saved correctly in the database, the url that is generated has this structure [example.com/u/username/view](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) and I am shown this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\messages.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main}`. this is the code present in the messages.php

```
<?php
require "config.php";
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header('location: '.BASE_URL.'login');
    header('location: '.BASE_URL.'register');
    exit;
}
//get all messages from database
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_messages WHERE message_owner=? ORDER BY id DESC");
$statement->execute(array($_SESSION['user']['username']));
$total_messages = $statement->rowCount();
?>
```

and this is htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^p/(.*)$/?$ post.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule  ^register register.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule  ^login login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule  ^u messages.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule  ^complete complete.php [NC,L]
```

```
                                                                                                                       .
```

Comment: What value does `$_SESSION['user']` have?

Comment: @arkascha do you mean in the database?

Comment: Nope, I refer to `$_SESSION['user']['username']` where you try to access the element with key "username" inside an array, `$_SESSION['user']`. You should check what value `$_SESSION['user']` actually has at that point in time. I suspect it is not what you expect, an array, but a string.

Comment: `$_SESSION['user'] = $username;
    header("location: ".BASE_URL.'u/'.$username.'/view');
}else{
    header("location: ".BASE_URL);
}` @arkascha

Comment: I have no idea where that code snippet comes from. It is not what I asked. But if `$_SESSION['user'] = $username;` indeed is where `$_SESSION['user']` is assigned the value then I'd say we can indeed assume that it most likely contains a string. Just as I predicted above. If that is a _string_ then what do you expect that `$_SESSION['user']['username']` resolves to? The element with key "username" _inside a string_ ? How should that work? That leads to the error message you get.